# PHP Radio Button in php table, need syntax to read its value to passon as session variable to other page. Image attached

Tags: php, radio-button

How to read value of radio button included in PHP table so that it can be passon as session.

Comment: Please go read some beginner’s tutorials if you can’t figure something that simple out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Take your radio button into a form, and set a method for that form.. for eg say POST.
So your code will be

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['radio1'];
$_SESSION['keyname'] = $value;
//or u can directly do it in this way
$_SESSION['keyname'] = $_POST['radio1'];
?>
```

now u can use that radio button value from the session variable as long as the session is active.